# Interpretation and Usefulness of Direct Product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, tensors

I'm currently reading *A Brief on Tensor Analysis* By J. Simmonds. It says,

Let the projection of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ on a vector $\mathbf{u}$ be denoted and defined as
$$\mathrm{Proj}_\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}\equiv (\mathbf{v}\cdot \bar{\mathbf{u}})\bar{\mathbf{u}}.$$
(And I understand the Geometrical meaning of it as well as I know the implication.) Further, It says

We can generalize this. The direct product $\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}$ (often denoted as $\mathbf{u}\otimes \mathbf{v}$) of two vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is a tensor that sends any vector $\mathbf{w}$ into a new vector according to the rule
$$\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{w})=\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{w})$$

But I really don't understand what's the geometrical meaning of it. For say $2D$ case, if $\mathbf{u}=2\hat{i}+3\hat{j}$ and $\mathbf{v}=-\hat{i}$ then what's this suppose to mean? Dot product supposed to give the length of the projection and then scale another vector by this amount.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, "direct product" is not a good name. That is usually used for other things. The symbol "$\otimes$" is usually called the "tensor product".

One way to think of it is that any linear map (i.e. a matrix) can be written as a sum of such tensor products.

For example, the matrix
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\3&4 \end{pmatrix} $$
Any vector $(x,y)$ is sent to $(x+2y, \; 3x+4y)$. Call the rows of the matrix $a_1 = (1,2)$ and $a_2=(3,4)$. Also call the standard basis vectors $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. Then in your tensor notation, the linear map represented by $A$ is the same as
$$ e_1 \otimes a_1 + e_2 \otimes a_2 $$

Comment: Also, if you know about dual spaces, it is more common to write matrices/linear maps as elements of $V \otimes V^*$, where $V^*$ is the dual space, in which case you don't need the dot product.